# vim freezes when changing colorscheme

Tags: vim

I start vim without custom config

```
vim -u NONE
```

Then, I call the colorscheme command to change the colorscheme, and vim simply freezes.

```
:colorscheme desert
```

It does not matter what colorscheme I specify, vim always freezes.

This happens on Mac OS only. I upgraded my macvim from 8.1 to 8.2, and I still see the freeze.

I don't think anything is wrong with my vim config since I am launching vim without custom config.

Any suggestions on how to either fix or debug the hang?

Comment: Which version of vim exactly, and which terminal are you using?

Comment: Does it also freeze if you change the colorscheme after starting it *normally* (without `-u NONE`)?

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes it does.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I tried opening vim using tcsh, bash and fish. I saw the freeze for all.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with Mac Terminal Itself. 
It used to freeze for me too but now I've switched from `bash` to `zsh` and everything works fine even for my Macbook Air 2017(8 GB) and on top of that I am using over 20 plugins which include a lot of linters and fixers.
Difference from `bash` to `zsh` is the reason that I am back to Vim again.
Also, if you have Catalina on your system, `zsh` is in there ,you'll just have to set it as default